# Exception: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished on using pubnub

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, mysql2, pubnub

I am using pubnub in my project and it is subscribed to a channel and in my subscriber I update my DB.
I am doing all this work in an initializer file like this

```
$callback_location = (lambda do |envelop|
  begin
    case envelop.channel
      when "iwm_driver_locations"
        last_location = LatLong.where(driver_id: envelop.message['driver_id']).last
        if last_location.lat != envelop.message['lng'] and last_location.lng != envelop.message['lat']
          l = LatLong.create!(
              lat: envelop.message['lat'],
              lng: envelop.message['lng'],
              driver_id: envelop.message['driver_id']
          )
        end
      when "iwm_chat"
        m = Message.create!(
            :author => envelop.message,
            :message => envelop.message,
            :timetoken => envelop.timetoken
        )
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    Rails.logger.info "****** Exception: #{e}"
  end
end)

$pubnub.subscribe(
    :channel => ['iwm_chat', 'iwm_driver_locations'],
    :callback => $callback_location
) unless $pubnub.subscription_running?
```

but my subscriber is throwing exception **ConnectionNotEstablished** in some attempts. However sometimes this code executes without issue.

I have tried to increase DB timeout and pool but same issue persists.
Any idea where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` before firing `$pubnub.subscribe`. It should help.

Comment: With this my code is working fine in development but on server in production mode its throwing same error in every case.